# App crashes on call to 'tableView endUpdates'

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

I'm currently working on an implementation of an [inline UIDate picker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18973573/ios-7-how-to-display-a-date-picker-in-place-in-a-table-view) inside of a UITableViewCell.

I'm able to show and hide this picker cell when I select the cell directly above where that cell should be inserted, which is the behavior that I expect. However, the app crashes if I select any other cells in the table view:

```
*** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3318.16.14/UITableView.m:1582
```

After looking at the [accepted answer to this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14027118/my-app-crashes-when-i-select-a-cell-on-a-table-view-but-i-cant-find-where-in-the), I added an exception breakpoint, and I've found out that the app is crashing at the call to `[tableView endUpdates];` in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    // Check to see if the "Only Alert From" row was selected. The cell with the picker should be below this one.
    if (indexPath.section == TimeOfDaySection && indexPath.row == HourTimeZoneRow  && self.timePickerIsShowing == NO){

        [tableView beginUpdates];
        [self showTimePicker];
        [tableView endUpdates];

    } else{
        [tableView beginUpdates];
        [self hideTimePicker];
        [tableView endUpdates];
        [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    }
    [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

That said, I'm not sure how to proceed. If I comment out the call to `[tableView endUpdates];`, the app won't crash when other cells are selected, BUT the cell with the picker view won't hide. Does anyone have any suggestions? Thank you!

EDIT: Below is my code for `showTimePicker` and `hideTimePicker`:

```
- (void)showTimePicker
{
    self.timePickerIsShowing = YES;
    self.timePicker.hidden = NO;

    //Create the index path where we insert the cell with the picker
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:HourTimeZoneRow + 1 inSection:TimeOfDaySection];

    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];

    self.timePicker.alpha = 0.0f;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
        self.timePicker.alpha = 1.0f;
        //This is the row where the picker cell should be inserted
        [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:HourTimeZoneRow + 1 inSection:TimeOfDaySection]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }];
}

- (void)hideTimePicker {
    self.timePickerIsShowing = NO;
    self.timePicker.hidden = YES;

    //Create the index path where we delete the cell with the picker
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:HourTimeZoneRow + 1 inSection:TimeOfDaySection];
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    //Delete the picker row
    [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25
                     animations:^{
                         self.timePicker.alpha = 0.0f;
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         self.timePicker.hidden = YES;
                     }];
}
```

EDIT 2: After reading [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6221248/iphone-app-crashes-when-a-row-of-uitableview-is-deleted?rq=1), I believe the problem may be with my `numberOfRowsInSection` method:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    switch (section) {
        case NotificationsSection:
            return TotalPreferencesRows;
            break;
        case RedZoneSection:
            return TotalRedZoneRows;
            break;
        case TimeOfDaySection:
            if (self.timePickerIsShowing) {
                return TotalTimeOfDayRows + 1;
            }
//            else if (self.timePickerIsShowing == NO){
//                return TotalTimeOfDayRows;
//            }
            else{
                return TotalTimeOfDayRows;
            }
            return TotalTimeOfDayRows;
            break;
        default:
            return 0;
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you post the code for your show/hide TimePicker methods? It would be helpful to see how are you displaying the timePicker

Comment: Yes of course, my apologies!

Comment: Please show the crash log. Also, add an exception breakpoint to show where it crashes.

Comment: Hi @Fogmeister, thank you, I will post the crash log. I did add an exception breakpoint; I will edit my question to make that more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your didSelectRowAtIndexPath, you call the hide method even though it might not be showing.  Make the `else` clause into an `else if`, like this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    // Check to see if the "Only Alert From" row was selected. The cell with the picker should be below this one.
    if (indexPath.section == TimeOfDaySection && indexPath.row == HourTimeZoneRow  && self.timePickerIsShowing == NO){

        [tableView beginUpdates];
        [self showTimePicker];
        [tableView endUpdates];

    } else if (indexPath.section == TimeOfDaySection && indexPath.row == HourTimeZoneRow  && self.timePickerIsShowing == YES){
        [tableView beginUpdates];
        [self hideTimePicker];
        [tableView endUpdates];
        [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    }
    [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if this is the source of the crash, but it's not recommended to call beginUpdates multiple times which you're doing in
`[tableView beginUpdates];
[self showTimePicker];
[tableView endUpdates];`
because showTimePicker calls `[self.tableView beginUpdates];`

Comment: Thank you Kim, I just took out the calls for being and end updates in 'didSelectRowAtIndexPath', but this time the crash occurred on the call to '[tableView endUpdates];' in 'hideTimePicker'

Comment: Just to be sure: Did you take out ALL calls to begin/endUpdates in didSelectRowAtIndexPath? Also the ones around `[self hideTimePicker];`?

Comment: Yes, I took out all calls to begin/endUpdates in didSelectRowAtIndexPath. The only places those calls exist are in my show/hideTimePicker methods.

Comment: Could you post the exception that is thrown?

Comment: It seems to be this: *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3318.16.14/UITableView.m:1582